# Calculating product purchases in a Financial Year | SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I would like to find out product purchases for 2 financial years (*FY16-17 & FY17-18*).

To go about it:

1. OwnerID: **101**, the first purchase is in 2014 with 3 purchases in FY17-18.
2. OwnerID: **102**, the first purchase is in 2011 with 1 purchase in FY16-17, 1 purchase in FY17-18.
3. OwnerID: **103**, the first purchase is in 2017 however **should not** be considered as he's a new customer with only 1 purchase in FY17-18. (i.e. *first purchase not considered if new customer*)
4. OwnerID: **104**, the first purchase is in 2016 but made 3 more purchases in FY16-17.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
        OwnerID INT,
        ProductID VARCHAR(255),
        PurchaseDate DATE 
);

INSERT INTO Test (OwnerID, ProductID, PurchaseDate)
VALUES (101, 'P2', '2014-04-03'), (101, 'P9', '2017-08-09'),
       (101, 'P11', '2017-10-05'), (101, 'P12', '2018-01-15'),
       (102, 'P1', '2011-06-02'), (102, 'P3', '2016-06-03'),
       (102, 'P10', '2017-09-01'),
       (103, 'P8', '2017-06-23'),
       (104, 'P4', '2016-12-17'), (104, 'P5', '2016-12-18'),
       (104, 'P6', '2016-12-19'), (104, 'P7', '2016-12-20');
```

Desired output:

```
FY16-17   FY17-18
-----------------
   5         4
```

I tried the below query to fetch records that aren't first occurrence and there by fetching the count within financial years:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OwnerID ORDER BY PurchaseDate) AS OCCURANCE
     FROM Test
     GROUP BY OwnerID, PurchaseDate)
WHERE 
    OCCURANCE <>  1
```

However it throws an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error does it throw? Remember: we cannot read neither your screen, nor your mind - you'll have to **show us** all the revelant bits and pieces!

Comment: Added the error

Comment: How do you define a fiscal year?

Comment: E.g.: Apr 1st 2017 to Mar 31st 2018

Answer (score 1):

The subquery needs to have an **alias** - try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OwnerID ORDER BY PurchaseDate) AS OCCURRENCE
     FROM Test
     GROUP BY OwnerID, PurchaseDate) subQry
WHERE 
    subQry.OCCURRENCE <>  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using IIF to separate the two fiscal years and subquery to filter out those with only one purchase

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(PurchaseDate >= '2016-04-01' AND PurchaseDate < '2017-04-01',1,0)) AS 'FY16-17',
       SUM(IIF(PurchaseDate >= '2017-04-01' AND PurchaseDate < '2018-04-01',1,0)) AS 'FY17-18'
FROM test t1
JOIN (SELECT ownerID, COUNT(*) count 
      FROM test 
      GROUP BY ownerID) t2 on t1.ownerID = t2.ownerID
WHERE t2.count > 1
```